# Ignore files and consider only sub-folders

Tags: shell

I would like to write a piece of shell to do the following:

1) go through all the **sub-folders** in current folder
2) if none of the files of a sub-folder contains word "ABC", then delete this sub-folder

```
#!/bin/bash

echo off
CurrentFolder=.

for f in $CurrentFolder
do
    if [ grep ABC $f/* | wc -l = 0 ]
    then
       rm -rf $f
    fi
done
```

The current folder contain some files, my first question is how to let `f` ignore files and only go through all the sub-folders.

My second question is, is `if [ grep ABC $f | wc -l = 0 ]` correct?

Comment: What if the sub-folders having file with `abc` has a sub-folders which do not contain `abc`?

Comment: Two remarks. First, `if grep ABC $f; then ... fi` should suffice -- the exit status of grep also signals whether a match was found (0/true) or not (1/false).  Second, `find` *might* do what you need if you pass it the right arguments... but I'm not sure.

Comment: We simply the thing... At the moment, all the sub-folders only contain files...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As to your first question, bizarrely enough

```
for d in ./*/; do echo $d; done
```

only gave me directories, even in /bin/sh. That sounds altogether too straightforward to be correct, though. Alternatively, you may try

```
find . -type d -maxdepth 1
```

(find type directory, only one level deep), which will include hidden directories and . itself.